# Spring Boot - "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'" - Start

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I have seen a lot of questions but the answers are not satisfying my problem...
I start with Spring Boot and I am completely lost.

The error is :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: pack.datas.entities.Degree
```

/// others lines

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: pack.datas.entities.Degree
```

---

**The entry point :**

```
package pack;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@RestController
@EntityScan
public class CandidatesRecruitmentApplication {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CandidatesRecruitmentApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**The classes :**

```
package pack.datas;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class DatasFactory {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public DatasFactory() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        if(this.dataSource == null)
            return this.dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        else
            return this.dataSource;
    }
```

---

```
package pack.datas.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Entity
@Table(name = "degree")
public class Degree implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8900492704842756948L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "pk_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "degree_i")
    private Integer degreeId;

    @Column(name = "degree_s_en")
    private String degreeEn;

    @Column(name = "degree_s_fr")
    private String degreeFr;

    protected Degree() {
    }

    public Degree(Integer id, Integer degreeId, String degreeEn, String degreeFr) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.degreeId = degreeId;
        this.degreeEn = degreeEn;
        this.degreeFr = degreeFr;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getDegreeId() {
        return degreeId;
    }

    public void setDegreeId(Integer degreeId) {
        this.degreeId = degreeId;
    }

    public String getDegreeEn() {
        return degreeEn;
    }

    public void setDegreeEn(String degreeEn) {
        this.degreeEn = degreeEn;
    }

    public String getDegreeFr() {
        return degreeFr;
    }

    public void setDegreeFr(String degreeFr) {
        this.degreeFr = degreeFr;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((degreeEn == null) ? 0 : degreeEn.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((degreeFr == null) ? 0 : degreeFr.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((degreeId == null) ? 0 : degreeId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Degree other = (Degree) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (degreeEn == null) {
            if (other.degreeEn != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!degreeEn.equals(other.degreeEn))
            return false;
        if (degreeFr == null) {
            if (other.degreeFr != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!degreeFr.equals(other.degreeFr))
            return false;
        if (degreeId == null) {
            if (other.degreeId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!degreeId.equals(other.degreeId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Degree [ " + degreeId + " - " + degreeEn + "/" + degreeFr + " ]";
    }

}
```

---

```
package pack.datas.controller;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class DaoController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    String home() {
        return "<h1>Test Program</h1>";
    }
}
```

---

**The pom.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pack</groupId>
    <artifactId>candidates-recruitment</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>candidates-recruitment</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.surefire/surefire-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

---

**The application.yml :**

```
# DATASOURCE (DataSourceProperties)
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/recruitments_db
    username: postgresql
    password: postgresql
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

# HIBERNATE (HibernateProperties)
hibernate:
  dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  show_sql: true
  hbm2ddl.auto: create

#SECURITY (SecuriyProperties)
security:
  user:
    name: TestU
    password: Test1
```

Please, I need your help !

Comment: just thought to point out that I ran into same problem and cause for me was jar downloaded by maven in first instance was corrupted. I cleaned maven and next build fixed issue.

Comment: I remove the **~/.m2/repository/org/hibernate** folder and rebuild with Maven. Its work!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Seems like you used `@Id` annotation from the wrong package in your `Degree` class. Change your import from `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` to `javax.persistence.Id`. That should help with the exception you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 javax.persistence.Id
```

instead of

```
org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
```

will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today.After some debugging,got to know that I annotated one of the fields in my model class with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` but didn't add the `@Id` annotation to that field.Adding one resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate jar was corrupted in local repository of maven,it was taking corrupted library every time, after deleting local maven repository issue resolved

C:\Users\user.m2\repository

Answer (score 0):

This error might be related to wrong database configuration in your project.
In your application.yml or application.properties file, you would be given wrong db name in "spring.datasource.url" .

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but I ran into the same problem and this is what fixed it:

```
diff --git a/pom.xml b/pom.xml
index 3a65505..96e5640 100644
--- a/pom.xml
+++ b/pom.xml
@@ -19,7 +19,7 @@
     <parent>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
-        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
+        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
         <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
     </parent>
```

Answer (score -1):

Encountered the same problem after importing my project to IntelliJ IDE.  Turned out it was easier than I thought  I went to *pom.xml* and right-clicked on `"+ Add as a Maven project"`. This solved the problem.